# Ubuntu crashes after clicking "Add to Bookmark" from the Current Folder Menu

Tags: nvidia, xorg, nautilus

Ubuntu crashes when I click "Add to Bookmark" from the "Current Folder Menu" (the strange thing is that it only happens the first time; the second and subsequent times, it won't happen). Note: by "crash," I mean the file explorer closes. And by "time," I mean each session, each time I turn on the computer.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10, X11/Xorg, and Nvidia drivers. Could that combination be the cause?

Is there any workaround to prevent this crashing?